# Trying to use defaultdict on lines in JSON

Tags: python

I'm interrating through lines of JSON and trying to create a dictionary of all the events that happen with a unique playerID but I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'append'`.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
import json, csv, sys
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
lastTimeByPlayer = defaultdict(int)
uniquePlayerID = defaultdict(list)
lasttime = 0
totalCircuits = 0
playerID = 0

allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(int))

for line in infile:
datum = json.loads(line)
time = int(datum['timestamp'])
try:
    pids = list(datum['playspace_ids'])
except:
    pids = []
for player in pids:
    if (time - lastTimeByPlayer[player]) > int(sys.argv[1]): #sys args is a set interval "dead time" interval that indicates a new player has arrived
        playerID = playerID +1
        uniquePlayerID[player].append(playerID)
    lastTimeByPlayer[player] = time
    if datum['key'] == "MakeCircuitCreated":
        allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID[playerID].append(time)
```

I feel like it has something to do with how I'm creating each instance of the `allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID[playerID]` key but I'm not really sure. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the erorr is in allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID, shouldn't you show how that is defined?

Comment: Sorry missed that when I was copying over the code

Comment: OK, so each element of that dict is itself a defaultdict. So why are you using `append`? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: So I actually need to store several things in the dict for each ID (if the event "MakeCircuitCreated" happens) so what I eventually I want is something like [ID1, {[time1, attributes], [time2, attributes]... [timex, attributes]], [ID2, [...]] , [IDx, [...] - right now I'm just trying to get the first part working (not sure if this cleared it up)

Comment: That's pretty confusing to me... how about posting an example of the intended `allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID` in your question so that you can use multiple lines.

Comment: ...and consider that ` {[time1, attributes], [time2, attributes]}` isn't valid python and is making us guess more about your intent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing your intent, but I think you either wanted:

```
allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID = defaultdict(list)
```

OR you are missing some sort of circuit id and you wanted something like:

```
        allCircuitsByUniquePlayerID[playerID][circuitID].append(time)
```

Comment: A bit more like the second (as I tried to explain above) - I actually need to store several things in the dict for each ID (if the event "MakeCircuitCreated" happens for that ID) so what I eventually I want is something like [ID1, {[time1, attributes], [time2, attributes]... [timex, attributes]], [ID2, [...]] , [IDx, [...] - right now I'm just trying to get the first part working (not sure if this cleared it up)